# Dual monitor webbrowsing with Firefox - Addon that opens links on the other window?

Tags: firefox

I often browse news aggregators like Reddit and I want to be able to have one Firefox window open on each of my two screens, and when I middle click on a link on my left screen, it will open up the tab on my right (2nd) Firefox window (and each successive middle click that opens links on my left window will also append consecutive tabs on the second window).

I know that there are some plugins that can open up new windows, but if I do that I'll have to many windows open and I'd rather manage my open news stories via 
tab bars rather than with windows (clearer, more efficient to browse, and easier to bookmark).

Is there a Firefox addon with which I can middle click on a link and it will open it in a new tab in my other window?

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1075157/links-from-external-software-opens-in-wrong-chrome-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this addon "[Monitor Master](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/monitor-master)" you have the options to "Open Link in Monitor One" or "Open Link in Monitor Two" for instance (you can open them in new tabs or windows) -and also "Move tab to Monitor One", "Move Tab to Monitor Two", and so on - so it's probably what you want.

More info here:

http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/17/enhance-firefox-multi-monitor-support-with-monitor-master/

Comment: thanks for the link; can this be tied to "middle click"?

Comment: You may need to combine it with a more advanced software such as the software called "Actual Multiple Monitors" for Windows

Comment: Unfortunately this extension no longer works with Firefox Quantum, anyone know of an alternative?