# Force Chrome to open links in new tab on specific window, when more than one is opened

Tags: google-chrome, links

I got 2 Chrome Windows always opened, one for browsing and another one for chatting.
My issue is that whenever I open a link from any app, it gets opened on the last Chrome window I used, so if I was chatting on window#2, it opens a new tab on that window. What I would like to have is every link opened on my browsing window#1, never on the chatting one.

Is that even possible? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Links from external software opens in wrong Chrome window](https://superuser.com/questions/1075157/links-from-external-software-opens-in-wrong-chrome-window)

Answer (score -2):

Opening the window as a popup does it:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
target="popup" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
Link Text goes here...
</a>
```

Comment: But how do you force all links "from any app" to open as popups?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, unfortunately.